# nginx + django + haystack = Server Error (500)

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-haystack, whoosh

I've cobbled together a small blog application in Django using Haystack with Whoosh backend for search. It runs nicely in development server (on the laptop) but search fails when site runs in nginx on a server (rpi).
I can access search page but any search results in Server Error (500), no additional info available from either nginx or django logs. I had RealtimeSignalProcessor on but turned it off - no change. Any pointer on how to attempt to debug this would be great.

Comment: Can you put "DEBUG=True" on your server and see the error message?

Comment: As Django receives the requests, it should print out those messages. 
Make sure that DEBUG=True is set in your Django settings file.
If Django isn't receiving the request, I would start at a higher layer like Nginx, port openings, and the network stack (IP address).

Comment: If on ubuntu run: `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` , it will give your error logs, assuming your are running on the production server. Then do like shown here: https://serverfault.com/a/410207/917402. That's how I solved my own  similar problem. It may work for you too

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing the obvious. With DEBUG=True i get: "The path to your Whoosh index '/path/to/my/mysite/whoosh_index' is not writable for the current user/group." which is then easily remedied by changing either file permissions or ownership of the folder to allow user, in my case nginx, write access.